# Rails, Ajax, OAuth and client-side API querying -- should it be done, and how?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, oauth

I used the OAuth gem to acquire an access token. In my code, I can write:

```
access_token.get('/1#{path}')
```

where path is some api query. But I want to do these queries asynchronously, client-side -- with no page refreshing.

I would like to know the best way to pass the API querying to the AJAX after authenticating with OAuth, *and* examples or an explanation of how to do so.

For example, I wish to display 20 followers per page, but when I click 'next page', it will just refresh the 20 on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're biggest problem will probably be the Same Origin Policy, i.e you will not be able to access data on the API providers domain.

You have two options.

First is to make your own server side dispatcher that will do your API calls for you. Call this from your client code. If you need to do any POST requests, then this is actually the only solution.

Second option depends on whether your API provider accepts JSONP requests. If it does, then you can at least do GET requests directly to the API end point without going via your own dispatcher.